# How to make playlist by javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did a background music which is hidden and only one music by mp3, it can autoplay and repeat when open the website.

I want to make a playlist, I tried many ways and found many ways, but it cannot be worked, how can I do if I put 3 or more than 3 musics into the website, the musics are in my computer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the [ask] page and improve the question so that we can help you properly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of great libraries that will be just right for you. My favourite one is **howler.js** - very easy calls and does pretty much anything you'd like to do with audio files.

- Howler.js: https://howlerjs.com/
- Sound.js: https://www.createjs.com/soundjs
- Waud.js: http://www.waudjs.com/
- Wavesurfer.js: https://wavesurfer-js.org/
- and many more audio.js out there :)

If you don't know how to create HTML markup of music player for your JS methods, above libraries provide great examples, so you can easily copy the stuff you need. Hope it helps!